# Find Minimum Vertex Connected Sub-graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, neo4j, connectivity

First of all, I have to admit I'm not good at graph theory.

I have a weakly connected directed graph `G=(V,E)` where `V` is about 16 millions and `E` is about 180 millions.

For a given set `S`, which is a subset of `V` (size of `S` will be around 30), is it possible to find a weakly connected sub-graph `G'=(V',E')` where `S` is a subset of `V'` but try to keep the number of `V'` and `E'` as small as possible?

The graph `G` may change and I hope there's a way to find the sub-graph in real time. (When a process is writing into `G`, `G` will be locked, so don't worry about `G` get changed when your sub-graph calculation is still running.)

My current solution is find the shortest path for each pair of vertex in `S` and merge those paths to get the sub-graph. The result is OK but the running time is pretty expensive.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: By "connected", do you mean weakly or strongly connected? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Directed_graph_connectivity)

Comment: @FalkHüffner it is weakly connected. I will add it to post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy with the results from your current approach, then it's certainly possible to do at least as well a lot faster:

Assign each vertex in S to a set in a disjoint set data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure.  Then:

- Do a breadth-first-search of the graph, starting with S as the root set.
- When you the search discovers a new vertex, remember its predecessor and assign it to the same set as its predecessor.
- When you discover an edge that connects two sets, merge the sets and follow the predecessor links to add the connecting path to G'

Another way to think about doing exactly the same thing:

1. Sort all the edges in E according to their distance from S.  You can use BFS discovery order for this
2. Use Kruskal's algorithm to generate a spanning tree for G, processing the edges in that order (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm)
3. Pick a root in S, and remove any subtrees that don't contain a member of S.  When you're done, every leaf will be in S.

This will not necessarily find the smallest possible subgraph, but it will minimize its maximum distance from S.

Comment: I've tried similar approach. Treat each vertex as the start of a mold, and then do a BFS for each mold. Stop the process until all molds meet each other. The problem is it will consume a lot of memory, the speed slows down as the iteration increases...

Comment: The difference is that I'm only asking you to do *one* BFS, and Kruskal's algorithm is very fast.  Also you don't need "all the vertexes to meet each other", you only need them to connect to the same tree.

Comment: Ah I see. Now the question is how could I `discover an edge that connects two 1 BFS sets`?
The second approach you mentioned won't work because I want to find the subgraph in realtime and the vertices and edges in the graph may change. Find the distance for all the edges in E to S will be too expensive. But still, that's a good point I haven't thought about. I should add the time restriction to the post.

Comment: You can stop when you process enough edges to connect S

Comment: If you're looking at the first expression, you know immediately when the BFS finds an edge that connects two sets, because you remember the source set for each vertex.  The disjoint set structure can tell you if they're already merged or not.

Comment: I will do the code and see if it works. Theoretically it should :) Will leave a comment here if any issue appears, otherwise I will accept this approach as an answer.

Comment: The potential problem for the second expression is not Kruskal's algorithm, but it's in Step 1: sort all the edges  according their distance to `S`. This step is very expensive since there will be 180 millions of edges. I cannot cache the result since the graph may change dynamically. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Instead of actually sorting the edges, you do a BFS from S and process each edge as you discover it.  Stop when S is connected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202741/discussion-between-top-deck-and-matt-timmermans).